# Why is TextOutW() failing with custom fonts greater than size 131px?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, graphics, gdi

I have a legacy .Net application that is using the gdi32 API to render custom images for clients. The clients sometimes provide custom fonts as otf files that are installed onto the machine. The "designer" fonts seem to render fine when the size is below 132. I have exceeded this size using stock windows fonts with no problem. So far all I have been able to find is that when trying custom fonts greater than 131 TextOutW() is returning false (which according to MS Docs means the function has failed). This doesn't tell me a whole lot. Can anyone provide insight as to why this might be happening or point me in the direction to better debug this issue?

Comment: How long is the string? Does it fail even on a string that is just a character or two? Where did you get 131px from?

Comment: Never heard of this, but what if you use DrawText or GDI+?

Comment: @Anders Please bear with me. I was just exposed to this functionality recently. We base our drawings off of an SVG file that our creative team supplies. They specify the font and size and we use that value and plug it into the cHeight param when creating the font using CreateFontW.

Comment: There is a size limit in GDI and GDI+. It is 32k for any pixel size. Do you perhaps hit it?

Comment: Anyone think it would be due to OTF vs TTF? Now that I'm looking at some of the stock fonts they all seem to be TTF and work fine.

Comment: Have you tried to get more information from `GetLastError()` or `RtlGetLastNtStatus()`? I know that `TextOutW()`, like most GDI functions, isn't documented to set last error value, but it may call other functions that do.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that the size ceiling is far smaller with .otf fonts as opposed to .ttf fonts. Making the switch to ttf fonts did the trick. I was unable to find the actual reason why GDI doesn't allow larger sizes with .otf fonts but this is a possible workaround for anyone with the same issue.